# How to get the list of the invited friends through facebook api

Tags: android, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

I want to implement the invite friend feature in my android app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android

**But I need to get the list of the invited friends, so when someone logged in to my app, I could show him the invited requests !**

There is nothing mentioned about that in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android.

How to do that ?

Comment: I upvoted it because someone downvoted for no reason.

Comment: @Snake thank you very much